# How to reduce order form to 3NF?

Tags: database, data-structures, database-normalization

I'm practicing normalization for class and had this as an example and I'm wondering how to reduce this to 1NF first hand?

[image]

The tables look alright to me, I don't see any repeating information, and the Product ID I think is a good Primary Key. For the first table above, would deleting the Due Date be a step? Also, for the Subtotal columns at the bottom, is that included in the data structure as well?

Thanks

Comment: To me, the tables look like an invoice.

Comment: @Will it is, that's why it's confusing

Comment: Someone turned your database schema into a paper invoice?  The cad!  What will you do to him once you catch him?

Comment: It's an invoice but it's a relation too. We could take (Selling Company, Invoice #) as PK, then everything else is an attribute of that. The tables make tuple-valued and relation-valued attributes which need to be normalized to get it into 1NF.

Comment: @reaanb thanks for that, do you reckon it is useful to include the bill to and ship to information in it's own table?

Comment: Quite likely, but since this is an exercise in normalization, don't guess at the tables. Work through the steps mechanically. First, convert the whole invoice to a tabular form with nested tables and the PK I identified. Then, unpack the composite attributes and nested tables to get to 1NF. Then, normalize partial dependencies and transitive dependencies, and see what additional tables you need in the process.

Comment: I have to say I like the shadow on that logo.